# Need Help to recursively import RDCs from a Folder and store each element into a Collection

Tags: python, import, collections

As written in the title and kindly need help, my script is almost ready but I have some troubles because it stores only the first element on the collection under its named from file.
I'm pretty new to python, however.[image]
Using the MapsImporter Plugin for scraping Google Maps from RenderDOC into Blender.

Original Question: https://github.com/eliemichel/MapsModelsImporter/issues/128

```
import bpy
import os
import sys
import glob

directory_im = 'C:/LowPoly2/'
files = glob.glob(directory_im + ".rdc")
for f in files:
    head, tail = os.path.split(f)
    collection_name = tail.replace('.rdc', '')
    bpy.ops.import_rdc.google_maps(filepath=(f), filter_glob=".rdc", max_blocks=-1)
    myCol = bpy.data.collections.new(collection_name)
    bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(myCol)
    for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        myCol.objects.link(ob)
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, so this code works with the test data on my rig:

```
import bpy
import os
import sys
import glob

directory_im = 'C:\\LowPoly2\\'
files = glob.glob(directory_im + "*.rdc")

# helper method to create a new LayerCollection
# also setting it to the active LayerCollection
# the Google Maps importer then puts the objects into that LayerCollection automatically
def create_coll(parent_layer_collection, collection_name):
    new_col = bpy.data.collections.new(collection_name)
    parent_layer_collection.collection.children.link(new_col)
    new_child_layer_coll = parent_layer_collection.children.get(new_col.name)
    
    bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = new_child_layer_coll
    
    return new_child_layer_coll
    

# create a master collection to batch import the files to, or re-use the currently active collection in the scene - up to you
master_collection =  bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection

# iterate over files
for f in files:
    head, tail = os.path.split(f)
    collection_name = tail.replace('.rdc', '')
    
    # create a new LayerCollection to import the objects to
    # I am storing the reference to it here in case you need to run further actions on it
    # e.g. changing color etc etc
    myCol = create_coll(master_collection, collection_name)

    # run the importer, it will work within the new sub-collection
    bpy.ops.import_rdc.google_maps(filepath=(f), filter_glob=".rdc", max_blocks=-1)
```

It becomes rather tricky because you need to deal with both `Collections` and `LayerCollections`, to be able to set an active layer collection. The first function creates just that, and returns a `LayerCollection` to be used, which is also set as active collection on the way. By doing that, the importer automatically places its objects in there "for free".

Answer (score 0):

I'm focusing on a multiple obj import and need to strenghten a bit the routine you published.
The idea is:

**Import OBJ recursively scanning on multiple subfolders, ONE by ONE**

**Apply Lily Texture Packer Plugin for each object imported and link to newly created material**

**Delete any other unused material**

**Save Lily Textured file .png in the same folder**

**Export a new FBX into the native folder**

(I saw that the tiles imported are shrinking from 500mb to 60mb, doing by hand, and it would be useful for massive import, i'm on 200 tiles at the moment).

```
import bpy
import os
import sys
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ImportHelper
from bpy.props import (BoolProperty,
                       FloatProperty,
                       StringProperty,
                       EnumProperty,
                       CollectionProperty
                       )
import glob



bpy.ops.outliner.orphans_purge()
directory_im = './3042726071604147-20-894/'
files = glob.glob(directory_im + "*.obj")


# helper method to create a new LayerCollection
# also setting it to the active LayerCollection
# the Google Maps importer then puts the objects into that LayerCollection automatically

def create_coll(parent_layer_collection, collection_name):
    new_col = bpy.data.collections.new(collection_name)
    parent_layer_collection.collection.children.link(new_col)
    new_child_layer_coll = parent_layer_collection.children[new_col.name]

    bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = new_child_layer_coll
    return new_child_layer_coll
    
# create a master collection to batch import the files to, or re-use the currently active collection in the 
scene - up to you

master_collection =  bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection

# iterate over files

for f in files:
    head, tail = os.path.split(f)
    collection_name = tail.replace('.obj', '')
    
    # create a new LayerCollection to import the objects to
    # I am toring the reference to it here in case you need to run further actions on it
    # e.g. changing color etc etc

    myCol = create_coll(master_collection, collection_name)

    # run the importer, it will work within the new sub-collection
    
    #bpy.ops.import_rdc.google_maps(filepath=(f), filter_glob=".rdc", max_blocks=-1)
    bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=f, filter_glob="*.obj;*.mtl", use_image_search=True, axis_forward='-Z', axis_up='Y')
    
    
bpy.ops.object.lily_texture_packer(spacing=0)  
obj_object = bpy.context.selected_objects[0] ####<--Fix

#for SlcObj in obj_select:
#    bpy.ops.object.material_slot_select(mat)
#    bpy.ops.object.make_links_data(type='Material')
    
    
ob = bpy.context.active_object

# Get material
mat = bpy.data.materials.get("Material")
if mat is None:
    # create material
    mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="Material")

# Assign it to object
if ob.data.materials:
    # assign to 1st material slot
    ob.data.materials[0] = mat
else:
    # no slots
    ob.data.materials.append(mat)
    
    
print('Imported Collection: ', obj_object.name)
    
    # bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=...)
```

Comment: Hello, is this an answer to the question or a call for new content ? If you need help, please use the comments or ask a new question

Comment: Hello, this is an ask for new help. I think it would be needed as a new question